# Postgres query - get all records of lowest price per ID

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have `items` table where I store information about items and their prices.
It looks like this:

`id | title |  item_code | price | site_id | store_id`

I want to select all item rows with the lowest price per `item_code`. It means the query should return ONE row per item_code in my table, which contains the lowest price.
I'm using PostgreSQL.

Not sure where to start. Example DB data:

```
id | title |  item_code | price | site_id | store_id
1 | Shampoo | TEST1 | 10 | 1 | 1
2 | Shampoo | TEST1 | 5 | 2 | 1
3 | Shampoo | TEST1 | 12 | 2 | 1
```

Comment: What output do you desire if there are several items with the same item code that sport the minimum price for this code ?

Comment: "I want to select all item rows with the lowest price per item_code. It means the query should return ONE row per item_code in my table,"  Those are two different things.  Which do you really want, all or one?

Answer (score 1):

Use `DISTINCT ON`:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ON (item_code) *
FROM items
ORDER BY item_code, price;
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=e7a65ff8718010f8fd1ff38dff4e23c2).

Comment: This one fails if there are multiple items with the same item_code having the minimum price.

Comment: @collapsar did you read: "the query should return ONE row per item_code in my table"?

Comment: I did, and it does not make sense if the complete item information is queried  - what is the point in a random selection among the min price items ?

Comment: @collapsar this is not my requirement. If you are unsure about it you can ask the OP. My understanding is that when the OP mentions *ONE row* this means *ONE row*.

Comment: Well, would you stand by your view if the OP asked for a query of all items with item_code XY, requiring the result set to have ONE row ? Anyway, I asked the OP.

Comment: @collapsar my view is based on what I read in the question. When something is not clear I ask for clarifications, so well done for asking.

Comment: @collapsar I think forpas' solution is correct because the question states "*the query should return ONE row per item_code*" which I also understand as "each item_code only once"

Comment: That's true. I don't care if there are multiple `item_code` rows with the minimum price, I need just one, no matter which one.

Answer (score 0):

Group your result set and use the `MIN` aggregate function:

```
    SELECT item_code
         , MIN(price)  min_price
      FROM items
  GROUP BY item_code
         ;
```

Join the result of this query with the original table if you need the the complete item record:

```
SELECT it.*
  FROM items it
  JOIN (
             SELECT item_code
                  , MIN(price)  min_price
               FROM items
           GROUP BY item_code
       ) gi ON ( gi.item_code = it.item_code )
 WHERE it.price = gi.min_price
     ;
```

See a live demo [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=b9cb75955a1f3b98954393b4f42f18ea) on dbfiddle.co.uk

Comment: Thanks, but I need to select the full row, not just the item_code - can you share how it can be adjusted? I tried it but it says that i must place all my fields in the GROUP by statement

Answer (score 0):

You can also use `ROW_NUMBER()`.

```
SELECT a.id, 
       a.title, 
       a.item_code, 
       a.price, 
       a.site_id, 
       a.store_id 
FROM 
(
    SELECT *, row_number() over(partition by item_code order by price) rn 
    FROM items
 ) a WHERE a.rn=1;
```